# Hydraulic erosion on heightMap creates weird artefacts

Tags: noise, procedural-generation

I have generated a heightmap using Ridgednoise. The end result looks bit weird so i wanted to give more natural look for it. After some googling around i decided on hydraulic erosion. I implemented 2 different approaches: [Ramantaru Games](http://ranmantaru.com/blog/2011/10/08/water-erosion-on-heightmap-terrain/) and [Hydraulic erosion](https://github.com/SebLague/Hydraulic-Erosion/tree/Coding-Adventure-E01) (it looks to be based on this [thesis](https://www.firespark.de/resources/downloads/implementation%20of%20a%20methode%20for%20hydraulic%20erosion.pdf)). But it does not create the expected results.

This is before:

[image]

And this is after erosion:

[image]

It is the same mountain, first the ridgenoise lines are clearly visible ant it is not natural at all, but the erosion, it creates these weird squiggli lines. Both approaches create same result. How can i make the after erosion look to be bit more smooth.

Comment: The material you start with does not look ideal, maybe try it on a perlin noise heightmap instead, you should also give more details like how many iterations you performed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be with the language i chose. I was using GDScript(godot scripting language). It is not statically typed. It seems like somewhere some value that was supposed to be float was int. When i converted to C# the issue went away.